# Search function filter on firebase if the input are keywords

Tags: firebase, cordova, ionic-framework, search, firebase-realtime-database

I am wondering how i can filter more of this query.
Basically, the search function works fine for 1 line words and consecutive line of words(including spaces), however if the current input is more likely keywords

ie. "stack overflow"

my query function can't query the title

> ie. "searching on stack and overflow"

Can you Advise? Thanks

```
Searchdata(ev: any) {

let val = ev.target.value;

this.QuizDataa = this.mqprovider.getSearchData(val).filter((item) => {
  return (item.Title.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
  })
}


getSearchData(data) {

let qwe = [];
this.afd.database.ref().child("Data/")
  .orderByChild("Title")
  .startAt(data)
  .endAt(data + '\uf8ff')
  .on("child_added", function(snapshot) {

   qwe.push(snapshot.val());
});
return qwe;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a simplest search function I could imagine. It simply splits the search query into single words and searches for them in the text. You could improve it by adding scores etc. But here we are getting into too much details. Google recommends using algolia (https://www.algolia.com/) for a full text search, there is community plan for free if you include their logo in your app.

```js
var key = "some words";

var text = "This is a text that has some words, that sometimes are in need of just being found by the algorithm";


var keySplit = key.split(" ");
var found = false;
keySplit.forEach(function(key){
  if(!found){
    found = text.indexOf(key) > -1;
  }
})

console.log(found)
```

Comment: hello @Lukasz, i actually had the same thought for the solution same as yours to split and store the input in array however, i had a hard time with the loop. Instead, i used forloop, and use indexof(key[i].toLowerCase()) to search each trimmed string to the var text